# C++ RTTI and Derived Classes

Tags: c++, inheritance, rtti

My C++ is a bit rusty.  Here's what I'm attempting to do:

```
class Cmd { };
class CmdA : public Cmd { };
class CmdB : public Cmd { };
...
Cmd *a = new CmdA ();
Cmd *b = new CmdB ();
```

First problem:

```
cout << typeid (a).name ()
cout << typeid (b).name ()
```

both return Cmd * types.  My desired result is CmdA* and CmdB*.  Any
way of accomplishing this other than:

```
if (dynamic_cast <CmdA *> (a)) ...
```

Second, I would like to do something like this:

```
class Target {
    public:
        void handleCommand (Cmd *c) { cout << "generic command..." }
        void handleCommand (CmdA *a) { cout << "Cmd A"; }
        void handleCommand (CmdB *b) { cout << "Cmd B"; }
};

Target t;
t.handleCommand (a);
t.handleCommand (b);
```

and get the output "Cmd A" and "Cmd B".  Right now it prints out
"generic command..." twice.

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Ah but `typeid(a).name()` will be `Cmd*` because its defined as `Cmd*`. `typeid(*a).name()` should return `CmdA`

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Typeid

Also, the base class of whatever you pass to typeid must have virtual functions, otherwise you get back the base class.

MSDN has a more eloquent explanation for that:

> If the expression points to a base
>   class type, yet the object is actually
>   of a type derived from that base
>   class, a type_info reference for the
>   derived class is the result. The
>   expression must point to a polymorphic
>   type (a class with virtual functions).
>   Otherwise, the result is the type_info
>   for the static class referred to in
>   the expression. Further, the pointer
>   must be dereferenced so that the
>   object it points to is used. Without
>   dereferencing the pointer, the result
>   will be the type_info for the pointer,
>   not what it points to.

Comment: Ahh yes. Another thing I was missing was having at least one virtual function in Cmd.  virtual ~Cmd () {}

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you are after double/multi dispatch... take a look at [here for some info for hacking it into C++](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple_dispatch#C.2B.2B).  Also take a look at the Visitor pattern.

I think what you would essentially want to do is the dynamic cast to figure out the type and then a static cast to call the appropriate handle command.  That being said my C++ is rusty too :-)